# RF communication between Pi and Arduino

Tags: pi-2, arduino, home-automation, openhab

I'm interested in making a home automation system with my raspberry pi 2 as the master device running the [openhab server](http://www.openhab.org/) and an arduino as the slave device that switches the relays and reads the sensors.

I have a 433mhz RF transmitter with a modulator and demodulator  with me. How do I make the two boards communicate with each other?

Comment: If you only have the one transmitter/receiver pair, then you can only communicate one way, correct?  I've edited your question and title somewhat to focus in on the question in the last paragraph rather than having it sound like something "you can imagine an entire book" about (see *[What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)* and perhaps take [the tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) again -- sometimes people new to Stack Exchange have trouble understanding we are a Q&A site, **not** a discussion forum).

Comment: Get two of those boards: https://talk2.wisen.com.au/product-talk2-whisper-node-avr/ one you run you remote node and another you connect tothe RPi via serial to receive the messages.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really my field (communication between Pi and Arduino) but I have done a little so I'll give an answer anyway.

RF comms are not noted for their high reliability so messages are usually wrapped in a protocol including a checksum to guarantee integrity.

One of the popular messaging protocols used on Arduinos is [Virtual Wire](http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/arduino/VirtualWire/).

I have implemented Virtual Wire for the Raspberry Pi in the form of a Python module.  See http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_vw

The module supports sending and receiving.  As goldilocks pointed out with a single transmitter/receiver pair you will have to decide whether the Pi or the Arduino is the sender.  That rather begs the question of how you will get any response.